# Error converting varchar to bigint in very peculiar situation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My intent is to retrieve all `CLIENT_CODE` converted to BigInt, to compare with a value passed as a parameter in the where clause from a 400 lines sql query. When execute the code below, I get the following error message:

> message error 8114 from sql server: "Error converting varchar to
>   bigint".

Test Code:

```
select CASE when (len (CLIENT_CODE) > 2 and isNumeric(CLIENT_CODE) = 1)
        then (CAST(SUBSTRING(TAB.CLIENT_CODE, 1, LEN(TAB.CLIENT_CODE)-1) AS BIGINT)) 
        else CLIENT_CODE end from TABLE TAB
```

Code Nested:

```
--HUGE_SQL... 
AND ((CASE when (len (CLIENT_CODE) > 2 and isNumeric(CLIENT_CODE) = 1)
        then (CAST(SUBSTRING(TAB.CLIENT_CODE, 1, LEN(TAB.CLIENT_CODE)-1) AS BIGINT)) 
        else CLIENT_CODE end) = @MyClient_Code) 
--... HUGE_SQL
```

Our `CLIENT_CODE` is `varchar(20)`, some have 0 characters, and some have letters, but almost every record is a number.

In my understanding, the case must be evaluated first, but it don't appear to be the case.

When i put the `isNumeric(CLIENT_CODE) = 1` in the where clause, in test code, it works. My problem is that i can't do it in this particular case, because the fact it is already nested in the where clause from a huge sql query, and adding the `isNumeric(CLIENT_CODE) = 1` there doesn't work, because it has a lot of other conditions.

Which is the best way to retrieve this data? Can someone figure it out how to do it? 
(It  will be very helpfull some kind of explanation of how is treated the functions vs case vs where)

Comment: Have you added `WHERE ISNUMERIC(CLIENT_CODE) = 1` and tried that?  Do you care that some rows will not be returned if they are non-numeric?

Comment: @JiggsJedi The WHERE clause won't help, because the filter may not run before the CASE expression.

Comment: @JiggsJedi, this CASE code is inside a nested select which is inside a  huge where clause from a huge sql query. When i put the `isNumeric` there, it keeps doesn't working, because of the others conditions in the monster where.

Comment: A `CASE` expression collapses to the data type with the highest precedence. So it's still trying to convert non-numeric values of `CLIENT_CODE` to `INT`. [You can get around this in a really yucky way using `SQL_VARIANT`](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/sql-variant-use-case/) but the `WHERE` clause won't necessarily help, since you can't control whether the `CASE` expression is executed prior to the filter. Also, `ISNUMERIC()` is terrible to rely on. It returns 1 for 9223372036854775808, for example, but try casting that value to a `BIGINT`.

Comment: Oh and +1 for using the word `case` with three different meanings, two in one sentence! Unfortunately the real fix for this is going to be to fix the data model. Why do you need to cast this column as a BIGINT when some of the values returned will still be strings? This makes little sense to me. Just remove the CAST - the presentation layer doesn't care if that came out as a BIGINT or string or SQL_VARIANT anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Case expression Returns `BIGINT` in one case and else it return `VARCHAR` data type .

For Case expression, in each case the returned data type must be same.

Also instead of using `ISNUMERIC()` use following

```
select CASE 
          when (len (CLIENT_CODE) > 2 and CLIENT_CODE NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
          then (CAST(SUBSTRING(TAB.CLIENT_CODE, 1, LEN(TAB.CLIENT_CODE)-1) AS BIGINT)) 
       end 
from TABLE TAB
```

`ISNUMERIC()` returns true for values like `123a1` , `346g2` it considers it as raise to power stuff, therefore use `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to get strings where only actual numeric values are present.

Comment: (Case is an expression, not a statement. It's a semantic thing but the different *is* important.) Anyway replacing ISNUMERIC() is sometimes a little more complex than that (think negative numbers, decimals, money, etc). The *real* fix is to stop storing BIGINTs in a string columns.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have always used NOT LIKE operator as a replacement for isnumeric(obviously not the best option after reading your comment), what do you suggest as a better replacement for isnumeric?

Comment: I'm just saying that `^0-9` is too restrictive for some situations (not for BIGINT, just in general), and it still doesn't solve the issue (e.g. 9223372036854775808 which I mentioned above - this will pass your check but still fail to cast to bigint). In 2012 and above, TRY_CONVERT() and TRY_PARSE() are much more reliable than a pattern match with all of these edge cases. Even more reliable? Using the right data type in the first place.

Comment: Do someone know why when i put the `else CLIENT_CODE` it keeps returning the error.
I mean, the solution to my problem was to ommit the `else` clause.

Comment: @Eduardo pretty sure that has already been explained. Why do you expect SQL server to be able to convert 'r0012fg4' to a BIGINT? To be able to be part of the CASE expression, it has to be able to do that. Read all the comments around for plenty of workarounds and most importantly the fix: stop storing both numeric and non-numerics in the same column, or stop trying to convert ANY of them to BIGINT.

Comment: I got it. I read right now the documentation, i didn't before realize that the result from both expression must be the same, and that was causing the error, even if my variable is a varchar. Thanks a lot for your help mates